# Ansible playbook password

Tags: ansible

New ansible user

Here is my playbook.

```yaml
---
- name: Creating Local User Account on RHEL Systems.
  hosts: hapansible05
  become: true

  vars:
    passwd: WSXcde1234


  tasks:
  - name: Creating Local User
    user:
      name: svc_cldscp
      password:  "{{ passwd | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      comment: svc_cldscp-ServiceAcct
      shell: /bin/bash
```

Keep getting this message on RHEL server

```
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

PLAY [Creating Local User Account on RHEL Systems.] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hapansible05]

TASK [Creating Local User] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
****fatal: [hapansible05]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "usermod: user 'svc_cldscp' does not exist in /etc/passwd\n", "name": "svc_cldscp", "rc": 6}******

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************
hapansible05               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: you have not a problem on password but on the user which doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

A [working practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) example for creating and configuring local users via [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) module with a filter for [Hashing and encrypting strings and passwords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-and-encrypting-strings-and-passwords) is

```yaml
---
- name: Create local user account on RHEL System
  hosts: rhel.example.com
  become: true

  vars:
  
    pwd: "WSXcde1234"

  tasks:

  - name: Create and configure user in local system
    user:
      name: "svc_cldscp"
      password: "{{ pwd | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      system: false          # Defaults to no
      createhome: true       # Defaults to yes
      uid: '1234'            # 
      group: '1234'          # Need to exist before
      shell: /bin/bash       # Defaults to /bin/bash
      comment: "Service Account"
      state: present
```